# how to filter field values based on other field values in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

Let us consider my models.py as

```
class ItemsInvoices(models.Model):
    RESERVED = 1
    NOT_RESERVED = 2
    ACCEPTED_BY_CUSTOMER = 3
    PO_OR_DEPOSIT_RECEIVED = 4
    DELIVERY_SET = 5
    NOT_READY = 6
    DELIVERED = 7


    ORDER_STATUS = (
        (RESERVED, 'Reserved'),
        (NOT_RESERVED, 'NOT Reserved'),
        (PO_OR_DEPOSIT_RECEIVED, 'Accepted by customer'),
        (PO_OR_DEPOSIT_RECEIVED, 'PO or deposit received'),
        (DELIVERY_SET, 'Delivery set'),
        (NOT_READY, 'Not ready'),
        (DELIVERED, 'Delivered'),
    )
     invoice_number = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
     order_status = models.IntegerField(default=RESERVED, choices=ORDER_STATUS)

class ItemsAddedInvoice(models.Model):
       item_invoice = models.ForeignKey(ItemsInvoices)

class StockMovements(models.Model):
      item_added_invoice = models.ForeignKey(ItemsAddedInvoice, blank=True, null=True)
      sales_group_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Here based on my sales_group_id i need to filter the ItemsInvoices table items whose order_status is set to RESERVED.(Here we need to filter based on sales_group_id because for each sales_group_id  we might have multiple item_added_invoice_id )

For example let us consider my database table for StockMovements as:

```
item_added_invoice_id  |    sales_group_id
 
 2206                  |   1
 2207                  |   1
 2208                  |   2
 2209                  |   3
 2210                  |   4
 2211                  |   4
 2212                  |   4
 2213                  |   5
```

for ItemsAddedInvoice

```
 id    | item_invoice_id
    
   2206  |  1236
   2207  |  1236
   2208  |  1236
   2209  |  1236
   2210  |  1236
   2211  |  1241
   2212  |  1241
   2213  |  1242
```

for ItemsInvoices

```
 id    | order_status

  1236  |  1
  1241  |  2
  1241  |  1
```

And finally in a modal popup we just need to display what are invoice_numbers with order_status==1 (i.e RESERVED )

Answer (score 0):

You can filter with:

```
ItemsInvoices.objects.filter(
    itemsaddedinvoice__stockmovements__sales_group_id=my_group_id,
    order_status=1
).distinct()
```

Here we thus filter such that we only get `ItemsInvoice` objects with a related `item_invoice` with `order_status` equal to `1`.

We can pass this to the context of a template rendering, for example with:

```
def some_view(request):
    invoices = ItemsInvoices.objects.filter(
        itemsaddedinvoice__stockmovements__sales_group_id=my_group_id,
        order_status=1
    ).distinct()
    return render(request, 'some-template.html', {'invoices': invoices})
```

with *`some-template.html`* the template to render, and in the template, then print the items with:

```
{% for invoice in invoices %}
    {{ invoice.invoice_number }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: when i am filtering this way i am getting this error Cannot resolve keyword 'stockmovements' into field.Choices are: order_status,invoice_number and import statement in my views is from stock.models import StockMovements

Comment: @VEERABABU: sorry made a typo. Should be fixed.

Comment: still i am getting an error Cannot resolve keyword 'order_status' into field.

Comment: @VEERABABU: the query should be done on `ItemsInvoices`, not `ItemsAddedInvoice`, hence the error.

Comment: Okay now can i print my invoice_number in modal popup in django template